# Elasticsearch retrieve matched field in multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a data structure where multiple fields are searched over, how can I retrieve the one that matched?

Example data:

```
person { 
    "id": 123, 
    "name": Bill, 
    "name": William, 
    "surname": Smith
}
```

And the query is something like:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "Will", 
      "fields": [ "name", "surname" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get ES to return

```
hits[
    type: person, 
    id: 123, 
    matched_name: "William"
]
```

What I need is to go over the two (or more) names `Bill` and `William` and return the one that best matches the query `Will`.

I'm aware of highlighting, and perhaps there's a way to use `"content" : {"type" : "plain"}` to return the matched field without highlighting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the `highlight` functionality. A field with multiple entries can be searched, and then only the matching strings are returned.

```
GET mynames/_search
{
  "fields": ["_id", "surname"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Will",
            "type": "phrase_prefix", 
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "surname"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "order": "score",
    "pre_tags": [""],
    "post_tags": [""], 
    "fields": {
      "names": {"fragment_size": 150, "number_of_fragments": 3}
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_id": "123",
        "fields": {
          "surname": [
            "Smith"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "names": [
            "William"
          ]
        }
      },
      ...
```

Where the matched field is listed under highlight. Note the removal of tags, which aren't necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution as of my knowledge is to use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) and a [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query:

```
GET mynames/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match" : {
            "query": "Bill", 
            "fields": ["name"],
            "_name" : "name"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match" : {
            "query": "Bill", 
            "fields": ["surname"],
            "_name" : "surname"
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

This will give the following result:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mynames",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "123",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "id": 123,
          "name": [
            "Bill",
            "William"
          ],
          "surname": "Smith"
        },
        "matched_queries": [
          "name"  // <== the "name" part matched
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is not exactly a drop-in replacement for [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query as it does some magic behind the scenes, but it should be possible to obtain the same behavior via a combination of `bool` and other queries, like `multi_match`, [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-match-query.html), [`dis_max`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html), [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you explained how to find whether the field came from "name" or "surname". But my question is "if there are multiple names, how to get the one that matches best?"

Comment: @MrMartin Thanks for the update. In your case I would separate the person record from universalization of the name. One way could be to use [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) (it will let you "map" Bill into William at index and query time). If you can't use synonyms, it might help to create a separate index that will allow to look up the "normal" form of a name (via [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester)).